# Accessing a model from another model's view or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I do a cross-model find in a way which conforms most closely to the MVC pattern?

I have a model, Istc.rb. In the index view that corresponds to this model, I want to do this:

```
   = "Last edited by #{User.find_by_id(istc.user_id).first_name}"
```

Clearly you can't have a model.find in a view - and not only is this a model.find, it's a find on a different model. But how would you refactor this?

I'm nervous about having a helper like this because it's still pretty close to the View layer:

```
module UsernameHelper
  def user_name(model)
    User.find_by_id(model.user_id) unless User.find_by_id(model.user_id).nil?
  end
end
```

Is the way to do it to have a scope on User?

```
# User.rb
scope :lookup, lambda {|model| where("id = ?", model.user_id)}

# username_helper.rb
module UsernameHelper
  def user_name(model)
    User.lookup(model).first unless User.lookup(model).first.nil?
  end
end
```

Or should the istcs_controller handle it? Or should there be a separate controller, which talks to both the Istc and User model?

Thoughts welcome, and I'd really like to see any sample applications which solve this sort of problem elegantly, too.

Comment: There is no forced 1 to 1 between models and controllers or views for that matter. So don't worry too much about that part. Use the models you need to build the view. Do you have an association set up between your models? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
Then you could use it to find the User through the Istc model.

Comment: To me scope is the best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rasmus said, if we make use of association its a simple think,
User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :istcs, :class_name => "Istc"
end
```

Istc Model:

```
class IStc < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

view:

```
<%= "Last edited by #{istc.user.first_name}" %>
```

If you are not happy with this the following would be the alternate solutions,

1. Write a helper method in application_herlper.rb(Since you are using in different controller views.
2. Write a instance method in Istc.rb model, that you could call from one the istc object directly from the view.